# AWS RDS - Allow ingress to IP ranges?

Tags: rds

Wondering how to allow ingress to a range of IP addresses to an RDS instance using a security group?

```
64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.80.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
207.126.144.0 - 207.126.159.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255
```

Comment: Add those IPs to the security group?

Comment: If you mean each IP in the range, won't that be literally hundreds, if not thousands of entries? Seems there must be a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS security groups take (even require, I believe... single IPs have to be entered as /32s) [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255, for example, is represented as `64.18.0.0/20`.

Comment: I found this site very useful for this usecase http://ip2cidr.com/